# Python class (Inheritance) using Person, Student, Professor class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am having so hard time to create the python code of Class-Inheritance. The parent class is "Person class" and the subclasses are "Student class" and "Professor class".

I have spent a lot of time, but this is too difficult to understand. I made 1 parent class, 2 subclasses and methods. 
I think a lot of my code needs to be modified and I do not know how to fix it.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age,department):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.department = department
    def get_name():
        return self.name

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(Person,i_d,GPA,advisor):
        self.Person = Person
        self.i_d = i_d
        self.GPA = GPA
        self.advisor = advisor
    def print_info():
        print("Name: %s, Age: %d, Department: %s, Advisor: %s " %(Person.name,Person.age,Person.department,Student.advisor))
    def reg_advisor():
        return Professor.name

class Professor(Person):
    def __init__(self,position,laboratory,student):
        self.position = position
        self.laboratory = laboratory
        self.student = student
    def print_info():
        print("Name: %s, Age: %d, Department: %s, Student: %s and %s " %(Person.name,Person.age,Person.department,Professor.student))
    def reg_student():
        return Student.name


Stu1 = Student("David", 30, "Computer", 20001234, 4.5)
Stu2 = Student("Tom", 30, "Computer", 20001234, 4.5)
prof1 = Professor("Andrew", 55, "Computer", "Full", "DT") # The last element is the list of student.

stu1.reg_advisor(prof1)
stu2.reg_advisor(prof1)
prof1.reg_student(stu1)
prof1.reg_student(stu2)

stu1.print_info()
stu2.print_info()
prof1.print_info()
```

The result should be:

```
# Name: David, Age: 30, Department: Computer, Advisor: Andrew)
# Name: Tom, Age: 30, Department: Computer, Advisor: Andrew)
# Name: Andrew, Age: 55, Department: Computer, Students: David and Tom)
```

I would much prefer that not to add or delete methods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your code. You would benefit from reading up on python classes, sub-classes and inheritance. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: There are a lot of errors starting from inconsistent variable name. E.g Stu1 to stu1, and misunderstanding of inheritance when it comes to initialization. I would suggest starting with two class, understand how single inheritance and composition works. Using of super to extend call inherited class and the move to multiple inheritance class C(A,B):pass :)